# Cast wrapper class to primitive in Xtend

Tags: java, casting, xtend

I have a for loop, in which I put `Double` values inside an array. Normally the values are from type `double` but as Xtend doesn't explicitly specify data types (and does this automatically) they are treaded as `Double`s.

I tried the following:

```
for (i : 0 ..< list.size) {
    array.set(i, list.get(i).myvalue as double);
}
```

But that doesn't seem to work, although no error occurs.

How can I cast `Double` to `double` or `Double[]` to `double[]`?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to cast at all. The following compiles fine:

```
val double[] array = #[1d,2d]
val List<Double> list = #[1d,2d]
for (i : 0 ..< list.size) {
   array.set(i, list.get(i));
}
```

Casting though also works.